# How can I enable encryption for SQLite3 in PHP5.3?

Tags: php, encryption, sqlite

The php manual for [SQLite3::open](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) has this information:

```
public bool SQLite3::open (
    string $filename
    [, int $flags = SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE 
    [, string $encryption_key ]]
)
```

> Opens an SQLite 3 Database. If the build includes encryption, then it will attempt to use the key.

I would like to use encrypted SQLite databases for a project I'm working on, but I can't find any information anywhere on how to build the SQLite module including encryption.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Perhaps it's so obvious no one has published any information or perhaps only commercial modules are available.
I've noticed that the developers of SQLite offer a proprietary [encryption extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html). Is this the only way to go?

Comment: Have you tried it out to see if its already enabled? (create/populate a DB with a password in 'open' then try to read from it without supplying the password)

Comment: Yes I have :) No luck

Comment: Obviously your build doesn't include encryption. Apart from bdb mentioned by desgleau, you could try mysql.

Comment: See this identical question on [so]. [SQLite with encryption/password protection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5669905/1068283)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks Michael, the identical question you point out has a suitable answer for my needs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Programming. It should have been migrated, but wasn't, and can't be now. See the linked Question in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gzrvTn), which has a SQLite-compatible SQL API and includes encryption as a part of the download.